# the specified module could not be found. \\?\d:\next.js\firstapp\node_modules\@next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node

Tags: next.js

I have installed the next.js app. When I run the command

**npm run dev**

I got this error

> the specified module could not be found. \?\d:\next.js\firstapp\node_modules@next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next failed to load SWC binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816589/next-failed-to-load-swc-binary)

Answer (score 25):

The issue is because the package is failing due to a missing library on the computer. fs-search requires Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64).

You can get the download here -> https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: This worked well. I didn't use the babel configuration.

Comment: I like this answer because it lets me keep using `SWC` instead of babel

Comment: This is the correct answer folks - fresh install of Windows 10, Next v12 and I got the above error. Quickly installed this and just re-ran `yarn dev` and it span up perfectly

Comment: I think this is the best answer. According to the Nextjs docs, "Next.js now uses Rust-based compiler SWC to compile JavaScript/TypeScript. This new compiler is up to 17x faster than Babel when compiling individual files and up to 5x faster Fast Refresh."

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

Comment: After installing VD Redist, I removed node_modules and package-lock.json and restarted the system. In the end, I installed the npm packages again.

Answer (score 11):

create a `.babelrc` file in the root folder of your project and include

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

then restart your application.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc