# Heroku application keeps crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

when I checked my Heroku logs, I get this error "sh: 1: swc: not found", tried to look up the error but I couldn't find anything. I've been on this for hours[image: This is the screenshot of my Heroku logs]

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

Comment: Sounds like your SWC module is not found. Is this a new deployment or an app that you've successfully deployed before? Next.js has decent docs about 'module not found' and swc load fail as linked above. This answer has more suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816589/next-failed-to-load-swc-binary . You could also try deploying to Render (https://render.com/docs/deploy-nextjs-app) and check to see if you get the same error.